# Issue with my quicksort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
public static String[] quickSort(String[] givenArray, int left, int right)
{
    int l = left;
    int r = right;
    //used to temporarily hold values for swapping process
    String temp;
    //arbitrarily picking a pivot point since I know the how much the array holds...
    String pivot = givenArray[33];
    while (l<=r)
    {
        while (givenArray[l].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
        {
            l++;
        }
        while (givenArray[r].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
        {
            r--;
        }      
        if (l <= r)
        {
            temp = givenArray[l];
            givenArray[l] = givenArray[r];
            givenArray[r] = temp;
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    if (left < r)
    {
        quickSort(givenArray, left, r);
    }
    if (l < right)
    {
        quickSort(givenArray, l, right);
    }

    return givenArray;
}
```

Hi guys, so I've been having a bit of difficulty learning the process of quicksort algorithm. In the above code, I'm trying to sort a String array using the quicksort method. For some reason the method doesn't work when I try to run it, and since it's a new topic for me I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to fix. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried executing your program, and suggest a small change   String pivot = givenArray[33] should be changed to   String pivot = givenArray[right];

```
please find the below example: 


public class Triangle{

    public static String[] quickSort(String[] givenArray, int left, int right)
    {
        int l = left;
        int r = right;
        //used to temporarily hold values for swapping process
        String temp;
        //arbitrarily picking a pivot point since I know the how much the array holds...
        String pivot = givenArray[right];
        while (l<=r)
        {
            while (givenArray[l].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            {
                l++;
            }
            while (givenArray[r].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            {
                r--;
            }      
            if (l <= r)
            {
                temp = givenArray[l];
                givenArray[l] = givenArray[r];
                givenArray[r] = temp;
                l++;
                r--;
            }
        }
        if (left < r)
        {
            quickSort(givenArray, left, r);
        }
        if (l < right)
        {
            quickSort(givenArray, l, right);
        }

        return givenArray;
    }

    public static void main (String arg[]){
        String[] givenArray = new String[]{"X","E","C","A"};
        printArray(quickSort(givenArray,0,givenArray.length-1));
    }

    public static void printArray(String[] sorted){
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");

        }
    }
}
```